# How to chain views for printing elements in C++20 or C++23?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

I can apply `std::ranges::for_each` to a view and print each element line this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges> // views::transform, views::filter
#include <algorithm> // ranges::for_each
using namespace std; namespace c = std::chrono;
namespace v = std::views; namespace r = std::ranges;

int main() {
    auto show_name = [](const string_view name) { cout << name << ' '; };
    const auto& db = c::get_tzdb();
    
    auto names = db.zones
        | v::transform([](const c::time_zone& z) { return z.name(); })
        | v::filter([](const string_view name) { return name.starts_with("Europe/Be"); });
    r::for_each(names, show_name);
    cout << " <- Europe/Be*\n";
}
```

But I would rather have something like this:

```
    auto names = db.zones
        | v::transform([](const c::time_zone& z) { return z.name(); })
        | v::filter([](const string_view name) { return name.starts_with("Europe/Be"); });
        | v::for_each(show_name);
    cout << " <- Europe/Be*\n";
```

But I believe there is no `std::views::for_each()`, right?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

I tried with `views::transform([](n) { cout << n; return 0; }` but because of "lazy", that does nothing.

Also, I tried something like

```
   cout << (db.zones
        | v::transform([](const c::time_zone& z) { return z.name(); })
        | v::filter([](const string_view name) { return name.starts_with("Europe/Be"); });
        | v::join) << "\n";
```

But I believe that is not how `join` works.

Comment: You should mind the distinction between an algorithm and a view/range. Algorithms are placed under `ranges` namespace, while view adapters are in `views`(corresponding classes are in `ranges`, but with a `_view` postfix). Copying/sorting data to various destinations are algorithms; there are no adapters for them.

Comment: Best you can get is `std::ranges::copy(db.zones
        | v::transform([](const c::time_zone& z) { return z.name(); })
        | v::filter([](const string_view name) { return name.starts_with("Europe/Be"); }), std::ostream_iterator<string_view>{std::cout, ",\t"});  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such utility in the standard.

However, thanks to [pipe support for user-defined range adaptors](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2387r3.html)
, you can easily create one through [`ranges::range_adaptor_closure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range_adaptor_closure) in C++23:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm> // for ranges::for_each

namespace pipe {
  namespace detail {
  template<class F>
    class for_each_closure : public std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<for_each_closure<F>> {
      F fun_;
    public:
      for_each_closure(F fun) : fun_(std::move(fun)) { }
      template<std::ranges::input_range R>
      constexpr auto operator()(R&& r) const {
        return std::ranges::for_each(std::forward<R>(r), fun_);
      }
    };
  }
  template<class F>
  constexpr auto for_each(F fun) {
    return detail::for_each_closure<F>(std::move(fun));
  }
};
```

Then you can use it like this

```
auto show_name = [](const string_view name) { cout << name << ' '; };
const auto& db = c::get_tzdb();

auto result = db.zones
    | v::transform([](const c::time_zone& z) { return z.name(); })
    | v::filter([](const string_view name) { return name.starts_with("Europe/Be"); })
    | pipe::for_each(show_name);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/914ceMnzx)

Comment: Do you happen to know what re reason is behind this obvious gap? What is the technical or conceptual difficulty that the addition of a `views::for_each(f)` faces? I don't know how ranges or views work and try to understand them. I understand Iterators (I think)...