# In C++23, can I pipe a ranges::view into for_each somehow?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

I'm really enjoying ranges::views in modern C++. Is there an idiomatic way I can directly pipe a view into for_each (or something equivalent, that allows me to execute code for every element in the view?)

Consider the following trivial program:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    auto m_directories = {std::getenv("HOME") + std::string("/Downloads")};

    auto files = m_directories |
                 ranges::views::transform([](auto e) { return fs::directory_iterator(e); }) |
                 ranges::views::join;

    ranges::for_each(files, [](auto &f) { std::cout << "Found file:" << f << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

This works great. But it feels like I should simply be able to pipe the view chain directly into for_each like:

```
m_directories |
    ranges::views::transform([](auto e) { return fs::directory_iterator(e); }) |
    ranges::views::join |
    ranges::for_each([](auto &f) { std::cout << "Found file:" << f << std::endl; }); // doesn't compile
```

But this fails and generates a spectacular log of compilation errors. Various copilots will actually generate code like the above (piping into for_each), but I can't manage to get it to work.

So, what's the most idiomatic way to construct a chain of views and then execute code for each element?

I suspect that part of the issue here is that views are lazy (perhaps the pipe syntax is only constructing chains of laziness)?

I'm using clang 14.0.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does c++20 ranges have any view functions that do not return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73195588/does-c20-ranges-have-any-view-functions-that-do-not-return-value)

Nothing changed between C++20 and C++23 in this regard.

Comment: @Fureeish Aha yes, it looks like the answer is discussed there (disappointingly), thank you. So it seems impossible. FWIW, I searched for multiple days before posting this but never found that link.

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167695/how-to-chain-views-for-printing-elements-in-c20-or-c23/77167778#77167778